# performance characteristics of radix sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am reading about performance charactersistics of radix sorting in Robert Sedwick algorithms in C++. Here author mentioned as below in section 10.6

Following link is online reference.

http://books.google.co.in/books?id=ZCchAeprwvYC&pg=PT605&lpg=PT605&dq=performance+characteristics+of+radix+sorts&source=bl&ots=1aH-jTEDZK&sig=zcIRfsIUn6_QtjhG7WR3IbWtGtA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sGq9Up69NseprAfx2IG4BA&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=performance%20characteristics%20of%20radix%20sorts&f=false

> The running time of LSD radix sort for sorting N records with w-byte
>   keys is proportional to Nw, because the algorithm makes w passes over
>   all N keys. This analysis does not depend on the input.
>
> For long keys and short bytes, this running time is comparable to N lg
>   N: For example, if we are using a binary LSD radix sort to sort 1
>   billion 32-bit keys, then w and lg N are both about 32. For shorter
>   keys and longer bytes this running time is comparable to N: For
>   example, if a 16-bit radix is used on 64-bit keys, then w will be 4, a
>   small constant.

My question on above text

1. Why author is comparint with N lg N for long keys and short bytes? How author came to conclusing here w and lg N are both 32 here?
2. Why author is comparing with N for shorter keys and longer bytes? How w is calculated here?
3. I am not getting what author is meant by short bytes and long bytes here?

Comment: Is my answer clear or should I try to explain something more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. He tries to present the complexity of a Radix sort using a standard notation (nlogn is easier to imagine at the first look than wN). Long keys and short bytes are just one of the possible cases in which you would use radix sort, so this is kind of an example (you get different complexities in different cases). lg(N) for N = billion is about 29,8 so it is close to 32 and therefore close to w = 32.
2. If you assume that you now compare 16-bit values, then your w = 64/16 = 4 (a single key consists of 4 16-bit values). This is a relatively small constant, so the total cost Nw is asympthotically close to N.
3. The "bytes" meant by author are the sizes of single pieces from which your key is build. So if you radix-sorted char arrays, you would probably sort "character-by-character", and your byte would be 8-bit (for a standard char). But if you radix-sorted some stranger elements, which are "made-of" for ex. 16-bit pieces, your byte would be 16-bit.